# Migrate Vm from VMware vCenter Server Version 5.1.0 to Vmware Fusion

Tags: vmware-fusion

I´ve a VM Ubuntu Server running under VMware vCenter Server Version 5.1.0. The VM has following files within the databrowser:

```
vm-clone.vmdk
vm-clone.nvram
vm-clone.vmx
vm-clone.vmxf
vm-clone.vmsd
```

Is possible to get this VM running with a VMware Fusion 4.1.4 (OSX) installation on my local hard drive?

With kind regards,

tbook

Answer (score 0):

Export it as an OVF/OVA from vCenter and then import it into Fusion. Bear in mind however that you have a pretty recent version of vSphere but a very old very of Fusion, this may cause problems.